# Mathematical annotations in a PDF file

Tags: latex, annotations

I like to annotate papers I read in a digital way. Numerous programs exist to help in this process. For example, on OS X one can use programs such as Skim or even Preview. However, making annotations is dreadful when one wishes to add mathematical annotations, such as formulas or greek letters. A cumbersome "solution" is to select the desired symbol one by one using the Special Characters palette, though this considerably slows down the annotation process.

Is there any way to add mathematical annotations to a PDF? The only two limitations that I would impose on a solution is that 1) the mathematical text needs to be selectable, i.e. it must be text and 2) I want to limit the number of programs I need to make the process as painless as possible.

Some of the more promising solutions I have tried include generating LaTeX with LaTeXiT, but it seems to be impossible to add a PDF on top of another PDF. Another attempt was to use jsMath to generate the symbols and copy-paste these as annotation using one of the jsMath fonts. This results in unreadable, incorrect characters.

Comment: I just write it in LaTeX code and leave is as that (in Skim). Certainly not beautiful, but readable. And you can copy and paste into a LaTeX document or LaTeXiT if you need to.

Comment: `pdftk` lets you layer a PDF on top of another (see the 'stamp' command) http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/

Comment: I've been looking to do this with a tablet pc for sometime. Skim is about the best software I've come by, and the annotations are still a bit too clunky for my liking. :(

Comment: @Eduardo Leoni: I certainly agree with you that this is the easiest way to proceed. However, LaTeX code is certainly not compact and often the space is missing to write out full LateX code. Especially when printing an annotated document this becomes problematic since you are constrained to the paper size.

@Geoff: though interesting, this is not exactly "easy" enough for annotations.

@Mica: I know how you feel. I recently moved from Skim to Preview since it reduces the hassle of having to remember to export. But I would say they are both about equally powerful (or limited, make your pick ;))

Answer (score 3):

Low-level solution: import the PDF to a LaTeX document, and place notes by providing their exact location ([full example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85651/is-there-are-way-to-annotate-pdfs-with-latex)), or use the pdfcomment package which places the comments automatically ([full example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex)). Both ways support LaTeX math code.

High-level solution: if you're ok with editing one pdf page at a time, then import a pdf page into [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), and annotate with LaTeX using [TexText](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417212/inkscape-with-textext).

Comment: Unhappily, you cannot add latex mathematical formulas in the pdfcomment. Such a shame !

Answer (score 1):

You can paste one PDF on top of another in [Context](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page) using layers.  I said a bit about how to do this in [my answer to the *How do I embed a source PDF onto an existing page in a PDF* qn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344997/how-do-i-embed-a-source-pdf-onto-an-existing-page-in-a-pdf/2355067#2355067)

Answer (score 0):

13 years later, and I stumbled on this page. I have a low budget web page tool I use for putting simple unicode math constructions into the clipboard and pasting in text annotation boxes.

[https://spot.pcc.edu/~ajordan/unimathcb/index.html](https://spot.pcc.edu/%7Eajordan/unimathcb/index.html)

Probably there are better tools out there that do general PDF annotation and allow for LaTeX input. But this tool meets the OP conditions 1 and 2.

Some unicode math characters are not represented by a given font, so that can be a limitation.